# Issue with transformation files in a nuget package

Tags: nuget

I am creating nuget packages for OSGeo.FDO and I am having the following issue.

FDO uses a `providers.xml` file that lists all the providers it can use. So I created a main package called `OSGeo.FDO` containing the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<FeatureProviderRegistry/>
```

And then, I am creating a nuget package for each provider. In each one of them I include a `providers.xml.transform` with, for example, the following:

```
<FeatureProviderRegistry>
   <FeatureProvider>
      <Name>OSGeo.PostgreSQL.3.6</Name>
      <DisplayName>OSGeo FDO Provider for PostgreSQL/PostGIS</DisplayName>
      <Description>Read/write access to PostgreSQL/PostGIS-based data store. Supports spatial data types and spatial query operations.</Description>
      <IsManaged>False</IsManaged>
      <Version>3.6.0.4707</Version>
      <FeatureDataObjectsVersion>3.6.0.4707</FeatureDataObjectsVersion>
      <LibraryPath>.\PostgreSQLProvider.dll</LibraryPath>
   </FeatureProvider>
</FeatureProviderRegistry>
```

When I install only one provider package, it works as expected, but once I install another one, it just doesn't change the `providers.xml` file at all. Although it tells me it has been modified and visual studio asks me if I want to reload it. I say I do, but it doesn't add anything to it.

Is there something wrong with what I'm doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NuGet XML transform can be a little quirky. The way you can make this work if the schema allows it is to make each  tag unique by adding an attribute. e.g. if you had

```
<FeatureProviderRegistry>
   <FeatureProvider name="OSGeo.PostgreSQL.3.6">
       etc...
   </FeatureProvider>
</FeatureProviderRegistry>
```

And then

```
<FeatureProviderRegistry>
   <FeatureProvider name="Other Name">
       etc...
   </FeatureProvider>
</FeatureProviderRegistry>
```

Then it should do what you want. I realize that this may not be the way you want your XML schema, but if you can do that, it can be a workaround.

Comment: Thank you David for your answer. It works for me, but it could indeed be a problem in some cases.